# How to get JaCoCo instrumentation code coverage while executing webApplication on server

Tags: jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin, test-reporting

I want to get a code coverage report (or tracking controller flow of an application) when I execute the some scenario on live application i.e. while application running in server, so I have refereed the official [Jacoco documentation](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/agent.html)  and did as fallows

As a first step, I tried to bind the jacoco agent to the application running port

```
export MAVEN_OPTS=-javaagent:/home/user/.m2/repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.4.201502262128/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.4.201502262128-runtime.jar=includes=*,output=tcpserver,port=6300,address=*,dumponexit=true
```

then I have started the server and executed some test scenarios by that time I have also requested jacoco to get the dump by executing following command

```
 mvn jacoco:dump
```

when I executed the above command first it showed like `java.net.BindException: Address already in use` then it printed as fallows

```
[INFO] Connecting to localhost/127.0.0.1:6300
```

When I stopped the server **jacoco.exec** has been generated to a known location there after I have requested to generate a jacoco report by executing the following command

```
mvn jacoco:report
```

Finally I got the report but when I open the index.html page it showed `0%` coverage.

you can reproduce my difficulty with following sample Spring MVC project

please download Spring MVC project from https://github.com/mkyong/spring4-mvc-ajax-example from the Github

In my case I am using WildFly 8.x server to run the project and add the following dependencies to downloaded projects pom.xml

```
 maven-surefire-plugin of 2.19.1 version
 jacoco-maven-plugin of 0.7.4.201502262128 version 
 junit of 4.12 version
```

Then clean and build the project by using following commands.

```
mvn clean install
```

once it is done get the .war file from target folder of the project and keep inside the wildfly `serverwildfly-9.0.0.CR2/standalone/deployments/` folder

Once the .war is deployed go to `/wildfly-9.0.0.CR2/bin/` folder and execute/run the `./standalone.sh` file or depending on platform you can run the`.dat/.sh` file

once project is deployed and server is started execute the following command

```
mvn jacoco:dump
```

it displayed like listening/connected to `localhost/127.0.0.1:6300`

Then execute some test scenarios and execute following maven command

```
mvn jaococ:report
```

Finally report will be generated with 0% coverage!.

Downloaded project can be found in  [MKyong website](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-4-mvc-ajax-hello-world-example/)

Please help me to get the code coverage report and any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JaCoCo requires the exact same class files for report generation that were used at execution time, so

- if report is completely empty, then classes were not provided
- if report contains classes but their coverage is 0%, then they don't match classes that were used at runtime - this is described along with other related information in JaCoCo documentation on page http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/classids.html

and in either case check existence of warnings in log.

## Update for updated question

Here is what I did:

- downloaded and unpacked JaCoCo 0.7.9 into `/tmp/jacoco/jacoco-0.7.9`
- downloaded and unpacked Wildfly 9.0.0.CR2 into `/tmp/jacoco/wildfly-9.0.0.CR2`
- cloned https://github.com/mkyong/spring4-mvc-ajax-example into `/tmp/jacoco/spring4-mvc-ajax-example` and built as `mvn verify`
- copied `/tmp/jacoco/spring4-mvc-ajax-example/spring4-mvc-maven-ajax-example-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war` into `/tmp/jacoco/wildfly-9.0.0.CR2/standalone/deployments`
- Wildfly started as `JAVA_OPTS=-javaagent:/tmp/jacoco/jacoco-0.7.9/lib/jacocoagent.jar=output=tcpserver ./standalone.sh` and got enough time to deploy application
- in directory `/tmp/jacoco/spring4-mvc-ajax-example` executed `mvn org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.9:dump org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.9:report` (note that version of used agent matches version of jacoco-maven-plugin) so that it created `/tmp/jacoco/spring4-mvc-ajax-example/jacoco.exec` and report `/tmp/jacoco/spring4-mvc-ajax-example/site/jacoco`:
  [image: report]
- opened `http://localhost:8080/spring4-mvc-maven-ajax-example-1.0-SNAPSHOT/` and did some actions
- executed `mvn org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.9:dump org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.9:report` again to get an updated report:
  [image: updated report]

Comment: thanks for the reply, I am getting report and it contains classes but code coverage is 0%, please can you suggest the way to match classes that used at runtime or please tell me how can I get the runtime classes

Comment: I think jacoco should bind with the JVM / server to get the runtime classes or please tell me how can I track the controller flow at runtime

Comment: @RajeshHatwar class files that are used at runtime on server should be exactly the same that are used during report generation literally

Comment: Please let me clarify this point, Dose JACOCO shows code coverage for a  web application without having any unit test cases and executing test scenarios manually on the web browser

Comment: @RajeshHatwar yes - how you execute application doesn't matter

Comment: ya, In my application two things I need to do! one is writing unit test cases and getting the code coverage report, application is so complex and contain lot of scenarios we are not able to write all the test case scenarios! but hopefully/possibly while doing manual testing we can cover at least 90%+ scenarios. so with the help of Jacoco if we are able to get coverage report while testing manually instead writing test cases it will be helpful just like `clover` do

Comment: I execute my application in eclipse IDE and finally for all the phases deployment will be done in Linux machine. One thing I want to inform you, I able to get proper code coverage report when I execute my application along with unit test cases (written in Junit ) but not without unit test cases

Comment: Please help me on this, I am almost barked my head to get the report! as you mentioned in second point I able to get the report but 0% coverage so jacoco didn’t get the classes that were used at runtime. But in integrated environment  like eclipse specially for maven projects target folder will contain all the required information so how can I get the class and feed for jacoco. Ok at least give some suggestion

Comment: @RajeshHatwar please update your question with precise instructions about how to reproduce your difficulty - ideally small runnable project (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and I'll try to help

Comment: @RajeshHatwar also bear in mind that Eclipse Compiler (that is executed by IDE) produces classes different from the ones produced by Oracle javac (that is executed by default by Maven)

Comment: Thanks for your reply I will precise with a small project and I will ping you

Comment: please download Spring MVC project from  `https://github.com/mkyong/spring4-mvc-ajax-example` the Github I have used `WildFly 8.x` server to run the project and added following dependencies `maven-surefire-plugin` of `2.19.1` version , `jacoco-maven-plugin` of `0.7.4.201502262128` version  and `junit` of `4.12` version. Then I have clean and build the project by using following commands. `mvn clean`, builded with `mvn clean install` once it is done get the `.war` file from target folder of the project and keep inside the wildfly server`wildfly-9.0.0.CR2/standalone/deployments/`

Comment: Once the `.war` is deployed go to `/wildfly-9.0.0.CR2/bin/` folder and execute/run the `./standalone.sh` file or depending on platform you can run the  `.dat/.sh` file

Comment: What I have done is once project is deployed and server is started and running at `http://localhost:6300/` path I have executed the `mvn jacoco:dump` command then it displayed like `listening to localhost/127.0.0.1:6300` after searching few criteria I have terminated the server and executed `mvn jaococ:report` it showed all the classes but `0%` coverage

Comment: you can refer the project executing steps at `http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-4-mvc-ajax-hello-world-example/` blog

Comment: @RajeshHatwar Answer was updated. No need to send many pings thru all available channels - please respect the fact that people have other tasks and they simply can't allocate all their free time just for you.

Comment: Godin indeed I am really sorry if it hurts, I was afraid the way I can reach you, but the only reason I have posted in other channel to inform I have edited my question. Thanks for your time please accept my gratitude.

Comment: I forgot to tell you, not able to start the wildfly server with  downloaded jacoco agent `jacoco-0.7.9` .jar because when try to execute `standalone.sh` by setting `JAVA_OPTS` server throned a error `Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : /home/user/tmp/jacoco/jacoco-0.7.9/lib/jacocoagent.jar
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: instrument
`

Comment: So I have gone with ` jacoco agent present in .m2 maven repository ` and successfully generated ` jacoco.exec ` and not able to convert `jacoco.exec` into reports  :] and generated `jacoco.exec` might contain test scenarios because it's size is more than 2.2 MB

Comment: @RajeshHatwar "Cannot read execution data version 0x1006" - I already told you to use exact same versions everywhere! and there are tons of mentions about that in internet - just google the message! "Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing" - also tons of reasons in internet, check that downloaded and unpacked files are not corrupted and have right permissions! "it's size is more than 2.2 MB" - yes it can be big, but that's not a problem - we generate reports for files over 100 Mb, increase max memory available for JVM that generates reports.

Comment: Godin Thank you very much for your time and help, thanks for investing your time to guide and help for me, I was getting error while starting wildfly server by setting `jacocoagent.jar ` "Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing"` this is because in ubuntu system while mentioning the absolute path of jacocoagent I suppose to keep inside single quotes! with out the quotes or within the double quotes it gives the above mentioned error. once again Thank you very much :)

Comment: Thanks Godin. This is very useful and worked without issues.