# How to get the code coverage of an application where selenium scripts executed on it?

Tags: selenium, code-coverage, jacoco, e2e-testing, jacoco-maven-plugin

I'm getting code coverage of my test scripts and not getting the code coverage of the application on which selenium scripts are executed

For example: If my application has 10 pages and my test suite has 5 test scripts, where each test script covers one page of my application.

I got the following command with respect to my scenario over internet. But not sure how this works

`-javaagent:<path-to-agent>/jacocoagent.jar=port=36320,destfile=jacoco-it.exec,output=tcpserver`

When executing all the test scripts, I'm getting the code coverage as 100%. Since the test script covers only 5 pages, I'm expecting a code coverage as 50%

Comment: is the application under test written in java? if so you can follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42133100/how-to-get-jacoco-instrumentation-code-coverage-while-executing-webapplication-o

Comment: Sure, I will give a try. Thank you